# Solving for a vector projection using least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have some arbitrary vector $v (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and a plane $x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 0$.

My goal is solve for the projection of the vector onto the plane using least squares.

The approach I took was the plane * $(V' * V)^{-1}$ * ($V'$ plane)

Obviously was way off since I got the answer incorrect. Can someone guide me in the general direction?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* If $u$ is a *unit* normal to the plane, then the orthogonal projector (i.e. the singular idempotent matrix that performs the projection) onto the plane is given by $P=I-uu^T$.